# Parse DOM to multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, dom, multidimensional-array

I want to Parse some DOM Content to a multidimensional array. Lets assume, I have this HTML Content

```html
<for model="customer" id="0" processed="0">

  <tag model="customer" value="name">name</tag>

  <for model="accounts_receivable" processed="0">

   <p>This is inside accounts_receivable</p>

  </for>

 </for>
```

I would like to parse this to:

```js
array(
  FOR => array (
    ATTRIBUTES =>
    SUBELEMENTS => array (
      FOR => array (
        ATTRIBUTES =>
        SUBELEMENTS =>
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I tried with parsing DOM via PHP with get ElementsByTagName, but its returning two for tags in the array.

The Key Point is, that the function should work with 2 layers or 20 layers.

Any good Idea?

Cheers,
Niklas

Comment: _“The Key Point is, that the function should work with 2 layers or 20 layers”_ – well then you most likely want a recursive solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function, doing this for "for" tag nodes. It ignores all other nodes, but parses recursively the complete DOM for all the for tag nodes.

```js
$doc->loadHTML($this->template, LIBXML_NOWARNING | LIBXML_NOERROR);

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('for');

$array = [];

if (!is_null($elements)) {
 foreach ($elements as $element) {
  if($element->getAttribute("processed") == false || $element->getAttribute("processed") != 1){
   array_push($array, $this->parseDomChild($element));
  }

 }
}

function parseDomChild($element) {

  $array = [];

  if(isset($element->tagName) && $element->tagName == 'for') {

   $array['nodeSelf'] = $element;
   $element->setAttribute("processed", 1);

  }

  if($element->hasChildNodes()) {

   $array['nodesChild'] = [];

   foreach($element->childNodes as $node) {

     array_push($array['nodesChild'], $this->parseDomChild($node));

   }

  }

  return $array;

 }
```